# Publishing Web application as Azure Market place app

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I want to develop a website and want to publish that as a Azure market place App.

For example I am expecting something similar to this, some one search for my app in Microsoft Azure Portal->Market place. Then click on my app icon that will redirect to my website.

Is this possible using Azure market place?

If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i publish my web solution to Marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37301911/how-can-i-publish-my-web-solution-to-marketplace)

Comment: The purpose of the azure market place is to provide software solutions on Azure. Not to just advertise your own offers and refer them to your own website. You can find the possible offer types here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace/publisher-guide-by-offer-type